# Is there a DocuSign api or integration avaliable for Oracle iProcurement application?

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently running Oracle Procurement and iProcurment application.

We are on Oracle EBS release 12.1.3.

We are using Oracle workflow AME for our PO Requisition approval processing.

We also are using DocuSign for our Approver eSignature and our supplier contract eSignature. However this process is not integrated with Oracle iProcurement Work flow and this process of DocuSign happen manually buy our organization buyers separately.

We would like to integrate our PO Requistion approval processes and sending documents to our approvers and suppliers through DocuSign automatically and include them in our current Oracle PO Requistion workflow process.

1- Does DocuSign support and has API that can be used with our Oracle PO Workflow process?

2- Can this integration be developped and supported if already does not exists?

3- What kind of DocuSign API licensing we do need and on the on going base.

I do appreciate all your feed back and support on this topic.

Thanks in advance for all your assistance.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: And please don't disclose any personal information.

Comment: I have checked, but we (DocuSign) don't currently know of an integration with EBS or iProcurement. If you start a project, please let me know by adding a comment to my answer (below) or contacting me at DocuSign. Thanks, Larry Kluger

Answer (score 0):

1- Does DocuSign support and has API that can be used with our Oracle PO Workflow process?

Yes, certainly. [The REST API](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) would be the first thing to check. Depending on your goals for the integration you may also be able to start with just the [Retrieve](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/retrieve-quick-start-guide-1.pdf) or PowerForms products.

2- Can this integration be developed and supported if already does not exists?

Yes. Oracle can develop the integration, or a third-party. DocuSign Professional Services organization could also be engaged to provide it.

3- What kind of DocuSign API licensing we do need and on an on-going base.

Depends on your volumes and needs. This question is best answered by the sales team. To start with, the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) provides free information and free sandbox accounts.

To use the API you can start with the [self-serve pricing](https://secure.docusign.com/develope). For larger volumes, please consult the sales group.